# Facebook Like button error: Not displaying number of likes on big button

Tags: css, facebook-like

After months of working correctly, the large version of the Facebook Like button has stopped displaying the number of "Likes". The compact version works correctly, but the big button hides the number. I am on a Mac, and the buggy behavior is consistent on Chrome, Firefox and Safari. You can see the big buttons NOT working on JoomlaDigger.com, and you can see all the small buttons working correctly on each article view.

After digging into the markup, the div with class "connect_widget_number_cloud" has element style "visibility:hidden". Very strange, since the markup does NOT show this CSS style, but Chrome CSS Inspector shows the element style.

This bug appeared on September 1st, 2011. Can anybody from Facebook comment on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also currently broken on [Facebooks own page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). And the bug has already been [filed](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20213).